# Where is eclipse platform plugin folder?

Tags: 12.04, installation, directory, eclipse, plugins

Today I installed Eclipse via `sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform`. Now I need to access the `plugins` folder and can't manage to find it anywhere. I don't have much experience using ubuntu, so I don't know if this is trivial but haven't find this information around. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in `usr/share/eclipse/plugins`.

You'll have to have root access to copy files here so type 'sudo nautilus' in the Terminal.

Comment: I found it and this actually answers my question. Other thing I needed to find (maybe should ask a separate question) is the `com.google` folder that I thought I would find there (but I haven't). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Should the `com.google` folder be in the `plugins` folder? If yes, and it's not there then feel free to create a new folder with that name!

Comment: But the thing I needed 'lives' inside this folder, haha. Creating one won't solve anything at all. But thanks for the idea =D.

Comment: Ahh ok sorry I understand you now! What exactly is it that you need? Try and google the exact name of it followed by eclipse. There's a good chance it's available online :)

Comment: I downloaded Eclipse Indigo again (not using terminal) and installed Google Plugins through `Install New Software` option inside `Help`. Then `com.google` folder where inside `Plugins`. Don't understand why this way it worked, but it did =D. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04, I had to do:

```
cd /usr/share/eclipse/plugins
```